# Is boolean interned in Java?

Tags: java, jls

The following code for [`Integer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) uses object interning:

```
Integer.valueOf("1")
```

It is not clear from API documentation whether this code for [`Boolean`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html) also uses interned object:

```
Boolean.valueOf("true")
```

*Obviously, it may. But does it have to?*

**UPDATE**

I agree that source code can explain **what actually** happens (BTW, thanks for the answers). To make the question less trivial, is there any part of Java API spec or JSL which tells **what MUST** happen?

It was natural to ask the question against the code like this:

```
String str = "true";
if (Boolean.valueOf(str) == Boolean.TRUE) { ... }
```

The outcome depends on whether "object interning" is guaranteed or not. It's better to avoid this code altogether and use `true` instead of `Boolean.TRUE` (rather than looking up details in any specs or sources), but it is a valid reason to ask the question.

NOTE: In fact, I didn't see guarantees of object interning for `Integer` in any googled specs. So, it may all be just an implementation detail nobody should rely on.

Comment: You can check for yourself by looking at the source code

Comment: You could also check by invoking it twice and checking if you receive the same Boolean instance twice or not. Why do you care anyway? This shouldn't change anything to your code.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, **is object interning outside of the specification?** Source-wise I guess it returns object `Boolean.TRUE` (or `Boolean.FALSE` for `"false"`). In fact, with such a small value set (only 2) these constants are enough to model the pool. But is it dictated by specification?

Comment: Well, if it isn't specified in the API specification (that's what the javadoc is), then the implementation is free to do whatever it wants.

Comment: @JBNizet, it's not that clear-cut. The specification is split into JSL and API (among others) and this is somewhere on the boundary of both. I agree - depending on these behaviours is obviously confusing (if not unreliable altogether). But when you see something like `if (Boolean.value(str) == Boolean.TRUE)`, it's a valid type of question.

Comment: Where did you read in the specification that `Integer.valueOf` might return a cached instance? It is an implementation detail of Sun / Oracle JDK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445024/does-autoboxing-call-valueof, that probably other follows; but it is not specified.

Comment: @Tunaki, that's why I ask the question. I couldn't find these parts anywhere. But I this didn't prove to me that such parts cannot exist.

Comment: The question is asking about `Boolean.valueOf` with the premise that "`Integer.valueOf` uses object interning", when the latter is in fact not specified. I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: @uvsmtid when I see that kind of code, all I see is a bug waiting to happen: the code relies on an undocumented feature of Boolean, and has no advantage over `if (Boolean.valueOf(str))` or `if (Boolean.parseBoolean(str))`. which are more concise, and will work whether valueOf() always returns Boolean.TRUE or not.

Comment: @JBNizet, totally agree - I even updated the question independently before seeing your comment. However, the fact of discussing this case and revealing uncertainties around possible unreliable outcome helps avoiding the line in question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7) guarantees that:

```
Integer i = 1;
Boolean b = true;
```

will use interning (at least between -128 and 127 for Integers, and for true and false for Booleans).

The relevant javadocs also guarantee that:

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(1);
Boolean b = Boolean.valueOf(true);
```

will return interned objects.

However there is no such explicit guarantees for `valueOf(String)`: although it is the case in the specific implementation you are using, it may not be the case with a different JVM or in future releases. In fact an implementation that would `return new Boolean(Boolean.parseBoolean(input))` would be valid.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Boolean.java#Boolean.valueOf%28java.lang.String%29), the boolean is parsed as:

```
public static final Boolean FALSE = new Boolean(false);
public static final Boolean TRUE = new Boolean(true);

public static Boolean valueOf(String s) {
    return toBoolean(s) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Where `TRUE` and `FALSE` are static (immutable) objects. So yes, parsed booleans are interned.

However, I agree with [@JBNizet's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37905530/is-boolean-interned-in-java/37905581#comment63263902_37905530) that one should not derive code contracts from the source code: as long as a feature is not documented, the developers of Java can change their mind. You better use [`Boolean.equals`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/boolean_equals.htm) to check whether two objects are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Boolean.java#Boolean.valueOf%28boolean%29):

```
public static Boolean valueOf(String s) {
    return parseBoolean(s) ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

Where [`TRUE`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/lang/Boolean.java#Boolean.0TRUE) is:

```
public static final Boolean TRUE = new Boolean(true);
```

If you're still not sure, define two variables:

```
Boolean a = Boolean.valueOf("true");
Boolean b = Boolean.valueOf("true");
```

and check whatever you want by yourself.