# Java: Why does "Character newChar = 'c' " work if Character is a wrapper class? How come it doesn't need a constructor?

Tags: constructor, factory, java.lang.class, java

These are both fine for me:

Example 1:

```
Character newCharacter = 'c';
```

Example 2:

```
Character newCharacterOther = new Character('c');
```

**But what are the differences?**

In the first example, how does the Character class know to set its value to "c" without needing a constructor for that?

Does it use a factory method behind the scenes? Can someone please explain to me how the compiler knows what to do?

I have a provided an image of the constructor of the Character.class in java.lang.

It even says that it's deprecated and that it shouldn't be accessed like that, but I am still confused a bit.

[image: Image showing the constructor of a java class]

Comment: Look up auto boxing.

Comment: Also for your specific question, this may be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31445024/does-autoboxing-call-valueof

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described [in the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2):

> Assignment contexts allow the use of one of the following:
>
> - ...
> - a boxing conversion (§5.1.7)
> - ...

Referring to [section 5.1.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7):

> Specifically, the following nine conversions are called the boxing conversions:
>
> - ...
> - From type char to type Character
> - ...
>
> At run time, boxing conversion proceeds as follows:
>
> - ...
> - If `p` is a value of type char, then boxing conversion converts `p` into a reference `r` of class and type `Character`, such that `r.charValue() == p`
> - ...

So, your line is equivalent to:

```
Character newCharacter = Character.valueOf('c');
```

Indeed, if you decompile your class, you will see that's exactly what gets invoked.

---

> But what are the differences?

`new Anything` is guaranteed to create a new instance of `Anything` (or fail with an exception). So, `new Character('c') == new Character('c')` is always false.

On the other hand, `Character.valueOf('c') == Character.valueOf('c')` *may* be true, because there is no requirement for a method invocation to return a new instance. Indeed, it is guaranteed by specification that you *won't* get a new instance on these two invocations.

This allows you to reuse existing instances, avoiding unnecessary allocations, thus saving memory.

Comment: Oh wow!! Thank you!!! :)) I was thinking that the compiler would do something along the lines of: "Character newCharacter = Character.valueOf('c'); " but I'm kind of a noobie still...